# Compiling applescript from a text-only source file

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to compile apple script code on the command line from a text source file, like you know, the way it is done in every *real* programming language?  I have an applescript .app file and it seems the only way to edit it is using the native script editor app. However not having a source text file results in all kinds of problems when the binary is loaded into different environments.  From what I can tell, it is not even possible to edit the source in the binary in many cases if the script editor is for whatever reason unable to load the binary file.

What I am trying to do is make it so that I can compile it in the environment it will run in. Any suggestions are appreciated...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the `osacompile` command.